# Error when checking input: expected input_6 to have shape (80, 80, 1) but got array with shape (80, 80, 2400) in image segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have a medical imaging dataset with a dimension of (80,80,2900), each image is 80*80. First I loaded the mat file of the data as follow:

```
data = loadmat('cardiac-dig.mat') 
images_LV = np.array (data['images_LV'])
val_data_size = 500
valid_images = images_LV[:,:,:val_data_size]
train_images = images_LV[:,:,val_data_size:]
valid_masks = masks[:,:,:val_data_size]
train_masks = masks[:,:,val_data_size:]
```

when I tried to fit the model using this:

```
model.fit(train_images , train_masks, epochs=2, batch_size=8)
```

I end up this error which says the input should be 4 dimensions:
Error when checking input: expected input_6 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (80, 80, 2400)

I tried to reshape the input to 4 dimensions using:

```
images_LV = np.reshape(images_LV, (-1, 80,80,2900))
```

but I got other error:
Error when checking input: expected input_6 to have shape (80, 80, 1) but got array with shape (80, 80, 2400)

I think that the input should be like (2900,80,80,1)? 
if you need more information I can share.

Comment: Your dimension cannot be (80,80,2900); normally, the third dimension is for the number of channels in each image. You probably mean you have 2900 images?

Comment: thanks for answering @desertnaut. I have 2900 samples which each is a gray image (say channel 1). since the data I have is from a mat file, its dimension is (80,80,2900). This means 2900 images of size 80*80

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I wanted to post the answer to those may have the same issue:

based on the shape of my dataset, (80,80,2900), I needed to change the dimension from 3 to 4. Also, it was necessary to reshape the dataset as follow:

```
***images = np.swapaxes(images, 0, 2)
images = np.swapaxes(images, 1, 2)
images = np.reshape(images, (-1, 80,80,1))
print(images.shape)
\\(2900, 80, 80, 1)***
```

After above change, I simply pass the data as the input of the model:

```
***train_images = images[val_data_size:,:,:,:]
model.fit(train_images , train_masks, epochs=5, batch_size=8)***
```